# How to implement prepareForSegue when I am not working with interface builders?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am moving from the world of storyboards to the one without. I was wondering how to implement the prepareForSegue method in this case. Because this method uses a segue identifier and the only way I know to provide a segue identifier is through the storyboard, I am not sure how to do this when I am not using any storyboard.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Vishisht,

You are going to want to override the [prepare(for:sender:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) function in your ViewController.

You are going to want to configure segue identifiers and then you can configure your segue as so:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegueIdentifier" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SomeViewController {
            // Configure your destination VC
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, if you are not using storyboards you should probably move away from using segues. I personally find it easier to present view controllers when I instantiate them programmatically and have a coordinator manage them. If you are curious about this, I can provide some examples.

Answer (score 4):

Segues are a storyboard thing. Notice prepareForSegue receives a UIStoryboardSegue. If you are moving away from storyboards, you are moving away from storyboard segues too.

From the docs on performSegue:

> The current view controller must have been loaded from a storyboard. If its storyboard property is nil, perhaps because you allocated and initialized the view controller yourself, this method throws an exception.